# UIScrollView scroll to bottom programmatically

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

How can I make a `UIScrollView` scroll to the bottom within my code? Or in a more generic way, to any point of a subview?

Answer (score 700, accepted):

You can use the UIScrollView's `setContentOffset:animated:` function to scroll to any part of the content view. Here's some code that would scroll to the bottom, assuming your scrollView is `self.scrollView`:

Objective-C:

```objectivec
CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, self.scrollView.contentSize.height - self.scrollView.bounds.size.height + self.scrollView.contentInset.bottom);
[self.scrollView setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:YES];
```

Swift:

```swift
let bottomOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.bounds.height + scrollView.contentInset.bottom)
scrollView.setContentOffset(bottomOffset, animated: true)
```

Comment: you probably want to the following to scroll to the bottom, instead of out of the scrollview:

    CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, [self.scrollView contentSize].height - self.scrollView.frame.size.height);

Comment: it was fun that my property was also self.scrollView, so this worked from copy paste

Comment: Your are not taking insets into account. I think You should prefer this bottomOffset: `CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, self.scrollView.contentSize.height - self.scrollView.bounds.size.height + self.scrollView.contentInset.bottom);`

Comment: this not work in Landscape mode! not completely scroll to bottom

Comment: `CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, self.scrollView.contentSize.height - self.scrollView.bounds.size.height + self.scrollView.contentInset.bottom);` does not really work either when insets are set

Comment: It wil not work properly if `contentSize` is lower than `bounds`. So it should be like this: `scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, max(scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.bounds.size.height, 0) ), animated: true)`

Comment: This handles bottom inset, and going beyond 0: `let bottomOffsetY = max(collectionView.contentSize.height - collectionView.bounds.height + collectionView.contentInset.bottom, 0)`

Comment: If you're using a collection view don't forget the bot safe area inset. `let bot = max(cv.contentSize.height - cv.bounds.height + cv.contentInset.bottom + cv.safeAreaInsets.bottom, 0)`

Comment: Why does this not work in viewWillAppear?

Answer (score 154):

Swift version of the accepted answer for easy copy pasting:

```swift
let bottomOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.bounds.size.height)
scrollView.setContentOffset(bottomOffset, animated: true)
```

Comment: bottomOffset should be let and not var in your example.

Comment: true, changed it. swift2 stuff :)

Comment: you need to check   if  scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.bounds.size.height > 0 otherwise you will have wierd results

Comment: This solution is not perfect when you have the new navigation bar.

Comment: @Josh, Still waiting for the day SO finds out about this

Answer (score 55):

Simplest Solution:

```
[scrollview scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(scrollview.contentSize.width - 1,scrollview.contentSize.height - 1, 1, 1) animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks.  I forgot I changed my scrollview to a UITableView and this code worked for a UITableView as well, FYI.

Comment: Why not just:
[scrollview scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, scrollview.contentSize.height, 1, 1) animated:YES];

Answer (score 32):

A swifty implementation:

```
extension UIScrollView {
   func scrollToBottom(animated: Bool) {
     if self.contentSize.height < self.bounds.size.height { return }
     let bottomOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.contentSize.height - self.bounds.size.height)
     self.setContentOffset(bottomOffset, animated: animated)
  }
}
```

use it:

```
yourScrollview.scrollToBottom(animated: true)
```

Answer (score 29):

Just an enhancement to the existing answer.

```
CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, self.scrollView.contentSize.height - self.scrollView.bounds.size.height + self.scrollView.contentInset.bottom);
[self.scrollView setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:YES];
```

It takes care of the bottom inset as well (in case you're using that to adjust your scroll view when the keyboard is visible)

Comment: This should be the correct answer... not the other ones that'll break if they ever have a keyboard pop up.

Answer (score 19):

Setting the content offset to the height of the content size is wrong: it scrolls the bottom of the content to the *top* of the scroll view, and thus out of sight.

The correct solution is to scroll the bottom of the content to the *bottom* of the scroll view, like this (`sv` is the UIScrollView):

```
CGSize csz = sv.contentSize;
CGSize bsz = sv.bounds.size;
if (sv.contentOffset.y + bsz.height > csz.height) {
    [sv setContentOffset:CGPointMake(sv.contentOffset.x, 
                                     csz.height - bsz.height) 
                animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if (sv.contentOffset.y + csz.height > bsz.height) {`?

Comment: @jeffamaphone - Thanks for asking. Actually at this point I'm not even sure what purpose the condition was supposed to serve! It's the `setContentOffset:` command that's important.

Comment: I presume its to avoid the setContentOffset call if it isn't going to do anything?

Comment: @jeffamaphone - It used to be that after device rotation a scroll view could end with its content bottom higher than the bottom of the frame (because if we rotate a scroll view its content offset remains constant, but the scroll view height may have grown due to autoresizing). The condition says: If that happens, put the content bottom back down at the bottom of the frame. But it was silly of me to include the condition when I pasted in the code. The condition *is* correctly testing for what it was testing for, though.

Answer (score 16):

A Swift 2.2 solution, taking `contentInset` into account

```
let bottomOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.bounds.size.height + scrollView.contentInset.bottom)
scrollView.setContentOffset(bottomOffset, animated: true)
```

This should be in an extension

```
extension UIScrollView {

  func scrollToBottom() {
    let bottomOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: contentSize.height - bounds.size.height + contentInset.bottom)
    setContentOffset(bottomOffset, animated: true)
  }
}
```

Note that you may want to check if `bottomOffset.y > 0` before scroll

Answer (score 15):

What if `contentSize` is lower than `bounds`?

For Swift it is:

```
scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, max(scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.bounds.size.height, 0) ), animated: true)
```

Answer (score 13):

Scroll To Top

```
- CGPoint topOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
- [scrollView setContentOffset:topOffset animated:YES];
```

Scroll To Bottom

```
- CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, scrollView.contentSize.height - self.scrollView.bounds.size.height);
 - [scrollView setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 11):

It looks like all of the answers here didn't take the safe area into consideration.
Since iOS 11, iPhone X had a safe area introduced. This may affect the scrollView's `contentInset`.

For iOS 11 and above, to properly scroll to the bottom with the content inset included. You should use `adjustedContentInset` instead of `contentInset`. Check this code:

- Swift:

```swift
let bottomOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.bounds.height + scrollView.adjustedContentInset.bottom)
scrollView.setContentOffset(bottomOffset, animated: true)
```

- Objective-C

```c
CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, self.scrollView.contentSize.height - self.scrollView.bounds.size.height + self.scrollView.adjustedContentInset.bottom);
[self.scrollView setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:YES];
```

- Swift extension (this keeps the original `contentOffset.x`):

```swift
extension UIScrollView {
    func scrollsToBottom(animated: Bool) {
        let bottomOffset = CGPoint(x: contentOffset.x,
                                   y: contentSize.height - bounds.height + adjustedContentInset.bottom)
        setContentOffset(bottomOffset, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

References:

- [adjustedContentInset](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/2902259-adjustedcontentinset)

Answer (score 7):

I also found another useful way of doing this in the case you are using a UITableview (which is a subclass of UIScrollView):

```
[(UITableView *)self.view scrollToRowAtIndexPath:scrollIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
```

Comment: FYI, that's a UITableView capability only

Answer (score 7):

Using UIScrollView's `setContentOffset:animated:` function to scroll to the bottom in Swift.

```
let bottomOffset : CGPoint = CGPointMake(0, scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.bounds.size.height + scrollView.contentInset.bottom)
scrollView.setContentOffset(bottomOffset, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 7):

If you somehow change scrollView **contentSize** (ex. add something to stackView which is inside scrollView) you must call `scrollView.layoutIfNeeded()` before scrolling, otherwise it does nothing.

Example:

```
scrollView.layoutIfNeeded()
let bottomOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.bounds.size.height + scrollView.contentInset.bottom)
if(bottomOffset.y > 0) {
    scrollView.setContentOffset(bottomOffset, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

With an (optional) `footerView` and `contentInset`, the solution is:

```
CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, _tableView.contentSize.height - tableView.frame.size.height + _tableView.contentInset.bottom);
if (bottomOffset.y > 0) [_tableView setContentOffset: bottomOffset animated: YES];
```

Answer (score 6):

**Swift:**

You could use an extension like this:

```swift
extension UIScrollView {
    func scrollsToBottom(animated: Bool) {
        let bottomOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: contentSize.height - bounds.size.height)
        setContentOffset(bottomOffset, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

Use:

```swift
scrollView.scrollsToBottom(animated: true)
```

Answer (score 3):

valdyr, hope this will help you:

```
CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, [textView contentSize].height - textView.frame.size.height);

if (bottomOffset.y > 0)
 [textView setContentOffset: bottomOffset animated: YES];
```

Answer (score 3):

Category to the rescue!

Add this to a shared utility header somewhere:

```
@interface UIScrollView (ScrollToBottom)
- (void)scrollToBottomAnimated:(BOOL)animated;
@end
```

And then to that utility implementation:

```
@implementation UIScrollView(ScrollToBottom)
- (void)scrollToBottomAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
     CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, self.contentSize.height - self.bounds.size.height);
     [self setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:animated];
}
@end
```

Then Implement it wherever you like, for instance:

```
[[myWebView scrollView] scrollToBottomAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Always, always, always, always use categories! Perfect  :)

Answer (score 3):

**For Horizontal ScrollView**

If you like me has a Horizontal ScrollView and want to scroll to end of it (in my case to most right of it), you need to change some parts of the accepted answer:

**Objective-C**

```
CGPoint rightOffset = CGPointMake(self.scrollView.contentSize.width - self.scrollView.bounds.size.width + self.scrollView.contentInset.right, 0 );
[self.scrollView setContentOffset:rightOffset animated:YES];
```

**Swift**

```swift
let rightOffset: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: self.scrollView.contentSize.width - self.scrollView.bounds.size.width + self.scrollView.contentInset.right, y: 0)
self.scrollView.setContentOffset(rightOffset, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 2):

As explained here
https://janeshswift.com/ios/swift/how-to-scroll-to-a-position-programmatically-in-uiscrollview/

We can create a custom `UIScrollView` extension as

```swift
extension UIScrollView {
    
    func scrollToTop(animated: Bool = false) {
        setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: contentOffset.x, y: -adjustedContentInset.top), animated: animated)
    }
    
    var bottomContentOffsetY: CGFloat {
        max(contentSize.height - bounds.height + adjustedContentInset.bottom, -adjustedContentInset.top)
    }
    
    func scrollToBottom(animated: Bool = false) {
        setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: contentOffset.x, y: bottomContentOffsetY), animated: animated)
    }
    
    func scrollToLeading(animated: Bool = false) {
        setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: -adjustedContentInset.left, y: contentOffset.y), animated: animated)
    }
    
    var trailingContentOffsetX: CGFloat {
        max(contentSize.width - bounds.width + adjustedContentInset.right, -adjustedContentInset.left)
    }
    
    func scrollToTrailing(animated: Bool = false) {
        setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: trailingContentOffsetX, y: contentOffset.y), animated: animated)
    }
    
    func scrollViewToVisible(_ view: UIView, animated: Bool = false) {
        scrollRectToVisible(convert(view.bounds, from: view), animated: true)
    }
    
    var isOnTop: Bool {
        contentOffset.y <= -adjustedContentInset.top
    }
    
    var isOnBottom: Bool {
        contentOffset.y >= bottomContentOffsetY
    }
    
}
```

Use It as --

```swift
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.itemsScrollView.scrollToBottom()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A good way to ensure the bottom of your content is visible is to use the formula:

```
contentOffsetY = MIN(0, contentHeight - boundsHeight)
```

This ensures the bottom edge of your content is always at or above the bottom edge of the view. The `MIN(0, ...)` is required because `UITableView` (and probably `UIScrollView`) ensures `contentOffsetY >= 0` when the user tries to scroll by visibly snapping `contentOffsetY = 0`. This looks pretty weird to the user.

The code to implement this is:

```
UIScrollView scrollView = ...;
CGSize contentSize = scrollView.contentSize;
CGSize boundsSize = scrollView.bounds.size;
if (contentSize.height > boundsSize.height)
{
    CGPoint contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;
    contentOffset.y = contentSize.height - boundsSize.height;
    [scrollView setContentOffset:contentOffset animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need animation, this works:

```
[self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, CGFLOAT_MAX) animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 1):

While `Matt` solution seems correct to me you need to take in account also the collection view inset if there is one that has been set-up.

The adapted code will be:

```
CGSize csz = sv.contentSize;
CGSize bsz = sv.bounds.size;
NSInteger bottomInset = sv.contentInset.bottom;
if (sv.contentOffset.y + bsz.height + bottomInset > csz.height) {
    [sv setContentOffset:CGPointMake(sv.contentOffset.x, 
                                     csz.height - bsz.height + bottomInset) 
                animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In swift:

```
   if self.mainScroll.contentSize.height > self.mainScroll.bounds.size.height {
        let bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, self.mainScroll.contentSize.height - self.mainScroll.bounds.size.height);
        self.mainScroll.setContentOffset(bottomOffset, animated: true)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution to scroll to last item of a table View :

Swift 3 :

```
if self.items.count > 0 {
        self.tableView.scrollToRow(at:  IndexPath.init(row: self.items.count - 1, section: 0), at: UITableViewScrollPosition.bottom, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't work for me, when I tried to use it in `UITableViewController` on `self.tableView` `(iOS 4.1)`, after adding `footerView`. It scrolls out of the borders, showing black screen.

Alternative solution:

```
 CGFloat height = self.tableView.contentSize.height; 

 [self.tableView setTableFooterView: myFooterView];
 [self.tableView reloadData];

 CGFloat delta = self.tableView.contentSize.height - height;
 CGPoint offset = [self.tableView contentOffset];
 offset.y += delta;

 [self.tableView setContentOffset: offset animated: YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CGFloat yOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;

CGFloat height = scrollView.frame.size.height;

CGFloat contentHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height;

CGFloat distance = (contentHeight  - height) - yOffset;

if(distance < 0)
{
    return ;
}

CGPoint offset = scrollView.contentOffset;

offset.y += distance;

[scrollView setContentOffset:offset animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that `contentSize` doesn't really reflect the actual size of the text, so when trying to scroll to the bottom, it will be a little bit off. The best way to determine the actual content size is actually to use the `NSLayoutManager`'s `usedRectForTextContainer:` method:

```
UITextView *textView;
CGSize textSize = [textView.layoutManager usedRectForTextContainer:textView.textContainer].size;
```

To determine how much text actually is shown in the `UITextView`, you can calculate it by subtracting the text container insets from the frame height.

```
UITextView *textView;
UIEdgeInsets textInsets = textView.textContainerInset;
CGFloat textViewHeight = textView.frame.size.height - textInsets.top - textInsets.bottom;
```

Then it becomes easy to scroll:

```
// if you want scroll animation, use contentOffset
UITextView *textView;
textView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(textView.contentOffset.x, textSize - textViewHeight);

// if you don't want scroll animation
CGRect scrollBounds = textView.bounds;
scrollBounds.origin = CGPointMake(textView.contentOffset.x, textSize - textViewHeight);
textView.bounds = scrollBounds;
```

Some numbers for reference on what the different sizes represent for an empty `UITextView`.

```
textView.frame.size = (width=246, height=50)
textSize = (width=10, height=16.701999999999998)
textView.contentSize = (width=246, height=33)
textView.textContainerInset = (top=8, left=0, bottom=8, right=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

To scroll to the bottom end, we have to work with the target view maximum height.

```
import UIKit

extension UIScrollView {

    func scrollToBottomOf(targetView: UIView, animated: Bool) {
        setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:targetView.frame.minX, y:targetView.frame.maxY), animated: animated)
    }
}

//func invocation example 
optionScrollView.scrollToBottomOf(targetView: self.optionsStackView, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is code is the modified version of the accepted answer.
The problem with the accepted answer is that it does not check if it needs to be scrolled or not.
In this piece of code i check if it needs to scroll then perform the action.

```
let contentHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height
let scrollViewHeight = scrollView.bounds.height
let contentInsetBottom = scrollView.contentInset.bottom
let bottomOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: contentHeight - scrollViewHeight +
contentInsetBottom)
if scrollView.contentOffset.y < bottomOffset.y {
    scrollView.setContentOffset(bottomOffset, animated: animated)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Xamarin.iOS** version for `UICollectionView` of the accepted answer for ease in copying and pasting

```
var bottomOffset = new CGPoint (0, CollectionView.ContentSize.Height - CollectionView.Frame.Size.Height + CollectionView.ContentInset.Bottom);          
CollectionView.SetContentOffset (bottomOffset, false);
```

Answer (score -2):

**Xamarin.iOS** version of accepted answer

```
var bottomOffset = new CGPoint (0,
     scrollView.ContentSize.Height - scrollView.Frame.Size.Height
     + scrollView.ContentInset.Bottom);

scrollView.SetContentOffset (bottomOffset, false);
```