# iOS App Mirroring "Screen Saver"

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, mirroring

I need to have my iPad application mirrored on an external screen exactly the way it runs on the device but after a certain period of inactivity the external screen should display a static image until the device receives touch input again. I've read a lot about handling multiple screens in iOS today but couldn't find a solution.

Is it possible to achieve something like that and if yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

*Summarized in one sentence: You can use UIViews on external screens like on the main screen.*

Quote of the **Displaying Content on an External Display** section from [Apple View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/CreatingWindows/CreatingWindows.html)

> The process for displaying content on an external display is described
>   in the following sections. However, the following steps summarize the
>   basic process:
>
> 1. At application startup, register for the screen connection and
>      disconnection notifications.
> 2. When it is time to display content on the
>      external display, create and configure a window. Use the screens
>      property of UIScreen to obtain the screen object for the external
>      display. Create a UIWindow object and size it appropriately for the
>      screen (or for your content). Assign the UIScreen object for the
>      external display to the screen property of the window. Adjust the
>      resolution of the screen object as needed to support your content. Add
>      any appropriate views to the window.
> 3. Show the window and update it normally.

The developer documents by Apple provide all required information (including samples): http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/CreatingWindows/CreatingWindows.html

Comment: I've already gone through this today. I know how to display a set of views on an external display but I would need to mirror the content displayed on the device. If i scroll in a UIScrollView on the device I need the scrolling to be exactly mirrored on screen

Comment: Since the external screen doesn't have the same resolution this won't give a nice result. Why not just rebuilding the screen elements and just also scrolling when the user scrolls on the main screen? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952412/uiscrollview-scroll-to-bottom-programmatically

Comment: As a last resort I will do that but I have over 10 completely different ViewControllers with several scrollviews each that need to be mirrored so this could be a lot of effort to sync each scrolling event...