# UITextView inside a UIScrollView inside a Popover is not fully visible when keyboard is displayed

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uitextview, uikeyboard, uipopover

I have a `UIPopover` with a `UIScrollView`inside it that contains a `UITextView` at the bottom.  When the keyboard shows, the popover is resized as the text view begins to be edited.  I want the code below to ensure the text view is visible:

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {

    CGRect visRect = textView.frame;
    [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:visRect animated:NO];

}
```

The problem is that the code does not make the entire text view visible. Instead, only the text view up to the bottom of the cursor is shown, as shown below:

[image]

How can I show the entire text view/ scroll the scrollview to the bottom?  I have tried this:

```
CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, self.scrollView.contentSize.height - self.scrollView.bounds.size.height);
[self.scrollView setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:YES];
```

as explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952412/uiscrollview-scroll-to-bottom-programmatically) but nothing works.

In addition, my scrollview is scrolled to the position shown AFTER the keyboard is moved into place.  Ideally I'd like the scrolling to happen before or during the keyboard movement.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Before scrolling to visRect, change the visRects origin as "visRect.origin.y = CGRectGetMaxY(visRect)". And then scroll to this rect.

Comment: @croyneaus4u.  Thanks, didn't help unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)notification {
NSLog(@"Notification: %s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ );
//
CGFloat textviewBottom = CGRectGetMaxY(self.commentsTextView.frame);
CGRect belowTextViewRect = CGRectMake(0, textviewBottom, 350.f, self.scrollView.contentSize.height - textviewBottom);
// NB! This works ONLY: 1) keyboardDidShow 2) Non-animated;
// Does NOT work: 1) animated, 2) keyboardWillShow, 3) textViewDidBeginEditing
[self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:belowTextViewRect animated:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@hey Dave

This By default Case in of `UIPopOverController`, whenever we used `UIPopOverControler` to display any `PopUpView` and in suppose that `PopUpView` height as large as can be covered by `KeyBoard` then in that case that `PopOverView`  Automatically gets Shrink itself.as you resign keyboard that PopUpView will expand itself automatically.I have faced same case.

**This is just my opinion** , you can change the origin of `CurrentView(parentView of PopUpView)` as keyboard going to display/hide so that `PopUpView` could display itself properly from and could get the appropriate space.

See Below Are the Delegate methods of UITextView Responds Back as editing start and end.

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
 //chnage the OriginY of PopUpView's SUperView
}
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{  
 //re Adjust the OriginY of PopUpView's SUperView
}
```

I hope it may helpful to you.

Comment: @DaveChambers at least you should have upVoted my effort, if it realy gave you any idea ....!!!! :)