# Scrolling the collectionview to the last footer view

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I know that we can scroll the collection view to a specific cell with the following method:

```
[self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionRight animated:NO];
```

In my case I would like to scroll to the end of the collection view who contains a footer view. If I'm using above code, then UICollectionView is scrolled to the last element but the footer view is not visible.

Answer (score 1):

Found this answer [UIScrollView scroll to bottom programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952412/uiscrollview-scroll-to-bottom-programmatically), which worked perfectly for my collectionview (despite the ongoing debate on the referenced answer).

```
CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, self.collectionView.contentSize.height - self.collectionView.bounds.size.height);
        [self.collectionView setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:YES];
```

Answer (score -1):

Use below code:

```
   [YourCollectionView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, YourCollectionView.contentSize.height) animated:YES];
```

Comment: The y point should be YourCollectionView.contentSize.height - YourCollectionView.frame.size.height