# How to compare 2 arrays and append last items to second array iOS Swift 3

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift3, items

Let's say i have a **firstArray** of PFObject[](from Parse SDK), and it has 7 items, i make a secondArray out of firstArray:

```
secondArray = firstArray
```

then i call a query to the database to retrieve updated data, they are now 10 items in firstArray.

I do something like this:

```
if firstArray.count > secondArray.count {
      let lastItems = firstArray.count - secondArray.count
     // lastItems = 3
}
```

How do i append those 3 last items to the end of the **secondArray** in their specific order?

> secondArray append item 8
>
> secondArray append item 9
>
> secondArray append item 10

I don't want to reloadData(), i just want to add the last 3 rows to my TableView like WhatsApp does, for example, otherwise the TableView will scroll to the top.

Thanks!

Comment: If you just don't want to scroll to the top, one way is to programmatically scroll to bottom immediately after reloadData(), e.g. with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952412/uiscrollview-scroll-to-bottom-programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you ask for a way to append it, this should work.

```
if firstArray.count > secondArray.count {
    for i in secondArray.count..<firstArray.count {
        secondArray.append(firstArray[i])
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

First append data to second array

secondArray.append(firstArray[index])

Then

```
self.yourTableView.beginUpdates()
var insertedIndexPaths = [indexpath_where_you_want_insertData]

self.yourTableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(insertedIndexPaths, withRowAnimation: .Fade)
self.yourTableView.endUpdates()
```

Answer (score 1):

if firstArray and secondArray are same
you can just do

```
secondArray = firstArray
```

and if in case you have updated secondArray and wants to append new data only

```
var counter = 0
while secondArray.count != firstArrayCount {
    secondArray.append(firstArray[firstArray.count+counter])
    counter += 1
    //insert new row in table
}
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, I haven't expressed my question correctly, i then need to update my TableView Datasource without reloading all data, only adding the last 3 rows to the end of the table, like WhatsApp does for example, of I call tableView.reloadData() it refreshes the entire TableView and scrolls it to the top

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to update your table view without reloading it, you'll have to use 
func insertRows(at indexPaths: [IndexPath], with animation: UITableViewRowAnimation)
You should look at this doc for better understanding of how to implement your task:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html

Comment: Yes, I know how to add rows to a tableView, i just needed the code to append last items to my secondArray, like the answer below this one ;)