# How to programmaticaly scroll a view when a button is clicked

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, nsnotificationcenter

I have a view which has a height of 1000 and it has a scrollView of the same height. When i click a button on the view i want to be able to move the view up to show lower sections of the view which is hidden on the screen frame. Since the screen has a field of view of 667 on iphone 6 for example.

I want to automatically scroll the view up to show the bottom of the view when a button is clicked.

Comment: Look into using this answer  : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38221875/9608620

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scroll the `scrollView` to bottom as below once you get the tap,

```
scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: scrollView.contentSize.height), animated: true)
```

You should be careful on setting the height of the view(currently you set it 1000) because if the `scrollView` does not have content more than this height it will not scroll. Better you keep the height of the view as the screen height and then you can scroll your `scrollView` to whatever position by changing y as above.