# How to set UIScrollView scrolled to bottom?

Tags: swift, xcode, uiscrollview

I want my scroll view (which is in top half of view) to be scrolled to the bottom of the scroll view when my app is booted up. I want it so that when the app boots up I cannot scroll down any further.

I have tried:

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 667)
scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x:0, y:self.view.frame.size.height )
```

However, this only brings my scroll view almost to the bottom. I can still scroll down a little, which I don't want.

I have also tried:

```
let bottomOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.bounds.size.height)
scrollView.setContentOffset(bottomOffset, animated: true)
```

but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIScrollView scroll to bottom programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952412/uiscrollview-scroll-to-bottom-programmatically)

Comment: If you read it, you'll see it's not a duplicate, because OP tried the method you linked and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code for moving scroll view to the bottom of the screen:

```
extension UIScrollView {

    func scrollToBottom() {
        let bottomOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: contentSize.height - bounds.size.height + contentInset.bottom)
        setContentOffset(bottomOffset, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Add this extension and try below code to access this extension for scroll to the bottom:

```
    scrlView.scrollToBottom()
```

If it is not working properly then you can also try to execute in mail queue:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   scrlView.scrollToBottom()
}
```

Let me know if you face any problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this extension if you like :

`extension UIScrollView {
   func scrollToBottom(animated: Bool) {
     if self.contentSize.height < self.bounds.size.height { return }
     let bottomOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.contentSize.height - self.bounds.size.height)
     self.setContentOffset(bottomOffset, animated: animated)
  }
}`

But i would suggest you to not use this as the code is little harder to maintain . What i would suggest is that use a TableView or Collection View inside your View Controller and do the following :

1. Invert your TableView or CollectionView using the below code . This will make the top the TableView or CollectionView go to bottom but the cell will be inversed:

> yourTableView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)

2. Then in invert your cells using the same code.

> cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)

So by default properties of ios , the tableview should begin from the top . Since we transformed it to show up in bottom of view , the content will be there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the NSScrollView equivalent to the UIScrollView Extension above.

```
extension NSScrollView {

    func scrollToBottom() {
        let variableHeight =  self.contentView.documentRect.height
        let fixedHeight = self.contentSize.height
        
        if (variableHeight > fixedHeight) {
            self.contentView.scroll(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: variableHeight))
        }
        
    }
}
```