# Programmatically scroll uiscrollview to bottom as uilabel grows in height

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uilabel, sfspeechrecognizer

I am using `SFSpeechRecognizer` to transcribe audio to text. As the audio is transcribed, I am printing it out as results come out to a `uilabel`, which is a subview of a `uiscrollview`. The `uilabel` is pinned to the top and bottom of the `uiscrollview`.

My problem is programmatically scrolling the `uiscrollview` to the bottom as the `uilabel` grows in height from the transcription.

I tried solutions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952412/uiscrollview-scroll-to-bottom-programmatically) but it does not work. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Code I've tried:

```
SFSpeechRecognizer().recognitionTask(with: request) { [unowned self] (result, error) in

                        guard let result = result else {
                            
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.transcriptionLabel.text = "We're not able to transcribe."
                            }
                            
                            return
                        }
                            
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.transcriptionLabel.text = result.bestTranscription.formattedString
                            
                            if self.transcriptionScrollView.contentSize.height - self.transcriptionScrollView.bounds.size.height > 0 {
                                let bottomOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.transcriptionScrollView.contentSize.height - self.transcriptionScrollView.bounds.height + self.transcriptionScrollView.contentInset.bottom)
                                self.transcriptionScrollView.setContentOffset(bottomOffset, animated: true)
                            }
                            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: You need to call layoutIfNeeded() before you set your content offset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again, the first thing you need to do is layout your subviews after updating the text so your computations are based on the new text.

Rather than jumping through a lot of hoops and trying to compute the contentOffset I would suggest using `scrollToRectVisible(_:animated:)`.

```
    view.layoutIfNeeded()

    let rect = CGRect(
        x: 0,
        y: transcriptionLabel.frame.maxY - 1,
        width: 1,
        height: 1)

    transcriptionScrollView.scrollRectToVisible(rect, animated: true)
```

That should scroll you to the bottom of the label, assuming that your label is a subview of your scrollView. If not, you will need to convert the label's frame to the scrollView coordinate space.

Remember to call `view.layoutIfNeeded()` after updating the text in your label and before scrolling.